# Different types in ChangingEventArgs in DevExpress

Tags: c#, events, devexpress

I have `CheckedComboBoxEdit` in a cell of a `GridControl`. When the `EditValueChanging` event of `CheckedComboBoxEdit` fires in `ChangingEventArgs` there are arguments such as NewValue and OldValue, I expect them to be the same type, but why `NewValue is string` and `OldValue is List<object>`?

Am I missing something?

Looks like I forgot to configure sime properties of `CheckedComboBoxEdit`?

Answer (score 0):

I've dealed with.

So, the OldValue is List when the value wasn't modified and string when the value was changed. Don't know why ChangingEventArgs behaves so.

So, in my case I check values like that:

```
if(e.OldValue is List<object>) return;
if(Equals(e.NewValue, e.OldValue)) return; //no need in this check, cause if OldValue is not List<object> then data was modified
/*...do somthing...*/
```